# SQL server, is it a way to use 2 while in a cursor

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here what I wanted to do in sqlserver with cursors.

I have two tables echeancier_a and echeancier_b which only match with the columns ref_a and ref_b. I'd like to use a third table to get them matched. The third table is matchtab in which I insert the quantity to be allocated from the table echeancier_b to echeancier_a.
I tried to use 2 cursors but I did get through because of the @@fetch_status.

I'm kind to the sql server world but would try to find out a way to get this result

**Table echeancier_a**

| ref_a | ech_a | qty_a | datelivraison_a |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 7 | 10 | 09/06/2021 |
| a | 11 | 5 | 11/06/2021 |

**Table echeancier_b**

| ref_b | ech_b | qty_b | datelivraison_b |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 1 | 2 | 11/07/2021 |
| a | 37 | 5 | 12/07/2021 |
| a | 45 | 7 | 13/07/2021 |
| a | 47 | 1 | 14/07/2021 |

**Table matchtab**

| ref_a | echa_b | ref_b | ech_b | qty_a | qty_b | qty_allocated | comments |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 7 | a | 1 | 10 | 2 | **2** | 2 qty_b allocated (ech_b=1) out of 10 qty_a (ech_a=7) |
| a | 7 | a | 37 | 10 | 5 | **5** | 5 qty_b allocated (ech_b=37) out of 8 qty_a (ech_a=7) |
| a | 7 | a | 45 | 10 | 3 | **3** | 3 qty_b allocated (ech_b=45) out of 3 qty_a (ech_a=7 is fully allocated), . it remains 4 from qty_b initially equals to 7 of ech_b 45 to be allocated to ech_a=11 |
| a | 11 | a | 45 | 5 | 4 | **4** | 4 qty_b allocated (ech_b=45) out of 5 qty_a, it remains only 1 qty_a to be allocated to ech_a=11 |
| a | 11 | a | 47 | 5 | 1 | **1** | 1 qty_b allocated (ech_b=47) out of 1 qty_a and ech_a=11 is fully allocated |

Thank you very much.

Comment: The "better" way is to not use while loops or cursors at all. They are horribly inefficient and can almost always be avoided.

Comment: Can you nest cursors? Yes. Typically you do that by opening and traversing the "sub" cursor inside of the outer cursor until it (the sub cursor) is exhausted. Then the loop of the outer cursor repeats. Your code has significant formatting problems so I (and likely most others) will not attempt to examine your code to understand it. Rarely is a cursor the best choice but it does have its uses.

Comment: @SMor thank you. I reformatted the code. What do you mean by sub and outer cursor?

Comment: what is your real goal, learn nested cursor or compute echeancier_a * echeancier_b ? can you show expected values ?

Comment: hi @jjdesign, I posted the expected values. Thanks!!

Comment: it's still not clear. how to choose or not rows from échéancier_b, how to compute qty_allocated. is there any calculations with date livraison? if the match is only with ref_a=ref_b , why is there only 5 rows in the result? (should be 2x4)

Comment: @jjdesign I completed the matchtab adding a column comments with the calculations rules. I wanted to to that fully in SQL server.